# Will the following circuit cause EMI-problems?

Tags: layout, emc, interference

I'm trying to get a feel for which circuits will have EMI-problems and which won't. To make things a bit more concrete, I've designed a super-simple LED-blinking circuit using the PIC16F1788 micro-controller.

I'm interested in hearing all you experienced engineers out there what your gut-feeling is - would this circuit be:

1. Clear-cut no risk what-so-ever of EMI-problems
2. Probably fine, but one would need to build it and do measurements to be sure
3. Seriously flawed, but might pass EMI-tests through luck
4. No chance of passing regulatory demands
5. None of the above

Here is a picture of the layout. I've drawn this circuit just for the purpose of this question.

[image: Circuit designed for this questoin.]

The IC is an PIC16F1788 in SO-package. It is decoupled close to its Vss/Vcc pins with a 0.1uF 0805 ceramic cap. 5V Power is supplied from the wall wart through a connector J1. A 1206 SMD LED is connected through a 680 ohm resistor R1 to RA0 pin on the PIC. There's a 4.7uF cap right next to the connector.

All pins are configured as digital outputs and driven low, except the RA0 which is connected through R1 to the LED and toggled high/low at 10Hz. The CPU is clocked at 32MHz from the internal oscillator.

Resistor R2 pulls the reset pin high (maybe unnecessary).

The board is 2-layer FR-4, 35um copper, with the bottom of the board  a ground plane (only interrupted at one point). There's a copper fill connected to ground at the top. The grounds are not via-stitched or anything.

RC4 is connected to the antenna-like trace which goes up vertically from the upper right half of the microcontroller.

The question is, would the above circuit pass regulatory requirements? Let's assume it was to be sold in the EU (although I don't think anyone would buy it :-) ).
I hope this question makes sense. I believe this circuit would be okay with the "antenna" grounded and probably okay if it was toggled at 1MHz, but not as clear cut. Am I right?

What are things to watch out for? Which small modifications would make the circuit worse? Which would make it better?

LED: https://www1.elfa.se/data1/wwwroot/assets/datasheets/kp-3216surck_eng_tds.pdf

PIC: https://www1.elfa.se/data1/wwwroot/assets/datasheets/PIC16F1788_9_eng_tds.pdf

Power supply: https://www1.elfa.se/data1/wwwroot/assets/datasheets/gs06e_eng_tds.pdf

Edit: Here's a schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: How about a schematic?

Comment: I can't imagine how a 10 Hz signal would cause emission problems, but I'm not an EMI/EMC expert. Still, this layout seems very convoluted to me. Why don't you have a via to the ground plane right next to LED1? Why are you routing a trace under the IC?

Comment: Well the trace under the PIC is an artefact of the way the program I used works (Fritzing). Both layers are uninterrupted ground under the PIC. A via next to the LED would of course have been better :-). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps the 32MHz signal inside the PIC would somehow leak out. Also, even if the LED is only blinking at 10Hz, it's driven by digital IO-pins, so at each transient there'll be much higher frequencies present. Still I think it's fine.

Comment: It may leak out through the supply line. This is one of the reasons for decoupling.

Comment: Yep, and I hear conducted noise is often harder to manage than radiated noise?

Comment: Two "concerns" (they might not be issues here) 1) the switching of the PIC (32MHz) 2) the switching of the LED. "But the LED is switching at 10Hz" thats nice... but the edges will be a lot faster, just like the edges of the 32MHz. put a ferrite on the +ve line going onto the card at least. Best thing would be a Pi filter